# How can I delete a shapefile using OGR?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, ogr

In my QGIS Python plugin, I use shapefile layers and I am having a problem rewriting existing shapefiles. Is it possible to delete a shapefile from disk using OGR?

Comment: If you're re-writing, you can just set the -overwrite flag in ogr

Comment: I don't know if `ogr` can target a shapefile directly, but in Python it's as simple as iterating over the files in your workspace and deleting the ones with the same name. See [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2012744/786131) for the basic idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is easy:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
if os.path.exists('your.shp'):
     driver.DeleteDataSource('your.shp')
```

Comment: `.shx` and `.prj` are well deleted but `.dbf` and `.shp` still exists and an error occurred `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. How to solve this or to check wich process is using those files ?